# Is there a single term for the study of mythology?

Tags: terminology

I know folklore studies are called "folkloristics" and people who study folklore are called "folklorists".

Are there equivalent terms for mythology? Is there a single term for the study of mythology, and what do we call someone who studies mythology?

Answer (score 4):

*Mythologist* - there is no such word in the *Longman Dictionary of English Language and Culture*. But there are other dictionaries of other languages and culture, for example: **[The Explanatory Dictionary of the Russian Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushakov_Dictionary)**:

> **[Мифолог](http://slovonline.ru/slovar_ushakov/b-13/id-30133/mifolog.html)** - Ученый, исследователь в области мифологии (Толковый словарь Ушакова)
>
> ```
> Mythologist - Scientist, researcher in the field of mythology
> ```